# Simple movement system only moves on the X axis (is a problem)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

When using this code on unity the character will only move on the X-axis. It is just a square that cannot slow down without direct input.

```cs
float _walkspeed;
float _inputHorizontal;
float _inputVertical;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    _rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    _walkspeed = 5.5f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    _inputHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    if (_inputHorizontal != 0)
    {
        _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(_inputHorizontal * _walkspeed, 0f));
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    _inputVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if (_inputVertical != 0)
    {
        _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(_inputVertical * _walkspeed, 0f));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add vertical force in y-axis in your `FixedUpdate()` method

```cs
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    _inputVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if (_inputVertical != 0)
    {
        _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, _inputVertical * _walkspeed));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do as Geeky Quentin mentioned, and also move your horizontal and vertical input into one function, either FixedUpdate() or Update(). If not, the character will move faster (or possibly slower) on the Y axis.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    _inputHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    if (_inputHorizontal != 0)
    {
        _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(_inputHorizontal * _walkspeed, 0f));
    }

    _inputVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if (_inputVertical != 0)
    {
        _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(_inputVertical * _walkspeed, 0f));
    }
}
```